# Можно ли применять в Map двойной ключ?

Tags: java, map, коллекции

Например, `Map<String*, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();`, там где *  можно поставить `< <String,String>, Integer >` например?

2.Для чего нужны одноэлементные коллекции? Первый раз слышу.Гугл мало информации дает.

Comment: Суть одноэлементной коллекции, как правило, сводится к переопределению методов интерфейса коллекции, максимально оптимизированных для одного элемента. Есть еще пустые коллекции, реализованные по похожему принципу. Первую применяют для передачи только одного значения, также часто видел такую конструкцию List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(someClass)); т.е. инициализировать коллекцию сразу с одним значением. Вторую используют, как правило, что бы избегать null-ов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от конкретной реализации `Map`. У `TreeMap` обязательным требованием для ключа является реализация интерфейса `Comparable`. Соответственно, можно определить собственный класс, имеющий два поля типа `String` и реализующий `Comparable`, а потом использовать объекты этого класса в качестве ключа. Ещё проще использовать `HashMap` вместо `TreeMap`. Ключом `HashMap` может быть любой хэшируемый объект, поэтому можно использовать, например, `List`, содержащий пару строк.

```
List<String> key1 = new ArrayList<>();
key1.add("qqq");
key1.add("www");
List<String> key2 = new ArrayList<>();
key2.add("eee");
key2.add("rrr");

Map<List, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key1, 1);
map.put(key2, 2);
```

Вторая часть вопроса слишком общая. Причём как определение "одноэлементная коллекция" слишком размытое, так и область её применения очень обширна. Например, какой-то метод ждёт в качестве аргумента коллекцию, а вам надо передать только один элемент.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("abc");
list.add(null);
list.add("def");
list.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null));
```